# Excel VBA code - Encountered with Data source query error

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing an error - "Data Query Refresh" while running an Excel based VBA code in my machine. Source query is also getting mismatched though I have passed input files into the excel.

My main concern is resolving Data source query error

Comment: [writing-the-perfect-question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [ask]

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Apologies for writing imperfect question - Will modify in detail.